# How to send multipart form data from js to Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fetch, multipartform-data

This is how I have my controller test, just to show what request structure works:

```ruby
post(
  :create,
  params: {
    play_session: {
      comment: "COMMENT",
      time_in_minutes: 10,
      video: fixture_file_upload("video.webm")
    }
  }
)
```

I am trying to reach this endpoint from JS with this:

```js
async function uploadFile(blob) {
  let play_session = { comment: "SUPER GOOD COMMENT", time_in_minutes: 23, video: blob };
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("play_session", play_session);

  try {
    let response =
      await fetch(
        "http://localhost:3000/front/play_sessions",
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: formData
        }
      );

    console.log("HTTP response:", response);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("Huston we have problem...:", e);
  }
}
```

But I get this error in the Rails console:

```
Started POST "/front/play_sessions" for ::1 at 2021-09-24 22:00:30 +0200
Processing by Front::PlaySessionsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"play_session"=>"[object Object]"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (Allocations: 1717)

NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "[object Object]":String):
```

I have tried to add headers to the `fetch` call like this:

```js
await fetch(
  "http://localhost:3000/front/play_sessions",
  {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    body: formData
  }
);
```

Then I have this error in the Rails console:

```
Started POST "/front/play_sessions" for ::1 at 2021-09-24 22:02:59 +0200
Processing by Front::PlaySessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"------WebKitFormBoundaryESNX0mluVZ8VIiry\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name"=>"\"play_session\"\r\n\r\n[object Object]\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryESNX0mluVZ8VIiry--\r\n"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms (Allocations: 520)


ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: play_session
Did you mean?  ------WebKitFormBoundaryESNX0mluVZ8VIiry
Content-Disposition: form-data; name
              action
              controller):
```

Comment: FormData's append expects the value as String or File. Try appending the hash one by one like `formData.append('play_session[comment]', 'super good comment)`. I'll post an answer if it works :)

Comment: @razvans bang! in the target ;). it works you can post the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FormData's [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) accepts `name`, `value` pairs where the `value` can be either a string or a Blob.

> **value**
>
> The field's value. This can be a USVString or Blob (including subclasses such as File). If none of these are specified the value is converted to a string.

Here, `formData.append("play_session", play_session)` you assign an Object.

Because Rails is smart to create Hashes & Arrays in params, you need to append the parameters from `play_session` one by one:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('play_session[comment]', 'SUPER GOOD COMMENT')
formData.append('play_session[time_in_minutes]', 23)
formData.append('play_session[video]', blob)
```

For nested attributes you should do:

```
formData.append('play_session[user_attributes][name]', 'Jack');
```

For Arrays:

```
formData.append('play_session[user_ids][]', "1");
formData.append('play_session[user_ids][]', "2");
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, make sure there's no **"Content-Type"** header when sending a formData object to rails. Only mention the method and the body. **Otherwise it won't work.**
Just saying as I've lost a lot of time yesterday because of that...